# Devexpress GridView count selected rows

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress

I have a Devexpress Data Grid with a number of rows loaded.

The following properties are set:

`MultiSelectNode=CheckBoxRowSelect`

`MultiSelect=True`

I have a function that iterates through all the Rows and checks,  `gridview1.IsRowSelected(x) = True`.

However the problem is, that even with the checkbox selected is checked it never shows as true.

The following code returns `0`

`Debug.Print(GridView1.GetSelectedRows().Count)`

Is there an easy way to check if the checkbox is checked?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about that 3P control, but usually there is a difference between Checked and Selected

Comment: Did you manage to try the GetSelectedFieldValues(...) method? Still doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon closer examination of the code a refresh method was being called which interfered with the grid `.getselectedrows`method.

Answer (score 0):

the following piece has been working for me in various parts of my app:

1. First specify the key field name which your datasource collection uses:

   <dvx:ASPxGridView ID="xgvGrid" runat="server" 
                           KeyFieldName="ID" ... >
   ...
   </dvx:ASPxGridView>
2. Then access selected rows IDs by:

   ...
   List<object> values = xgvGrid.GetSelectedFieldValues("ID");
   ...

   You can obtain the selected row's count by calling `values.Count` afterwards.

HTH

Comment: Yes, finally managed to get it sorted. I was calling a refresh method which made the grid loose the row selection.

Comment: @DaveB then consider posting your own answer and accepting it to close the question so to speak.